# База данные на sqlalchemy

Tags: python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy

Есть 2 таблицы которые будут содержать данные о юзере, а вторая данные о посте.
благодаря get_user_model, данные о пользователе не дублируются. Цель, написать код который будет позволять добавить в таблицу в нужную графу и нужную строку данные, а не просто дублировать их.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.update(
    DEBUG=True,
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI='sqlite:///telegram.db',
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS=False
    )
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=True)

    status = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=True)
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy='dynamic')



class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)

    file_id = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=True)
    caption = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=True)
    inline = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=True)
    btnUrl = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))



def get_user_model(tel_id):
    global db
    model = User.query.filter_by(id = tel_id).first()
    if model == None:
        model = User(id = tel_id)
        db.session.add(model)
        db.session.commit()
    
    return (model)
```